# MongoDB query to find and extract value from array

Tags: mongodb

I want to extract value from array.
right now i have

```
db.getCollection('typeE').distinct("list.name",{"list.name":"C"})
```

I have such structure

```
object(1)"list":[{"name":"A","value":10},{"name":"B","value":20},{"name":"C","value":50}]
object(2)"list":[{"name":"D","value":100},{"name":"E","value":70}]
```

I want to receive 50 , but right now receive only object(1)

I also tried

```
db.getCollection('typeE').distinct("list.value",{"list": {$elemMatch: {"name":"C"}}})
```

but it's return array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your doing this the wrong way. What you want (if I get you right) is to get distinct `value` of subdocuments having `"name": "C"`

you should try this :

```
db.getCollection('typeE').aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$list"},
  {$match: { "list.name": "C"}},
  {$group: {_id: null, distinctValue: {$addToSet: "$list.value"}}}
])
```

this will output:

```
{"_id": null, "distinctValue": [ 50 ] }
```